# Android EditText problems

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have created an EditText like this

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/myid" 
              android:hint="This is my hint"
              android:textColorHint = "@color/white"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:textSize = "20sp"
              android:textColor = "@color/white"
              android:textStyle = "bold"
              android:background ="@drawable/mybackgroundimage"
              android:fitsSystemWindows  = "true"
              android:includeFontPadding = "true"
              android:singleLine="true" 
              android:cursorVisible = "false"

              >
    </EditText>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Its  in a table layout. i have 2 problems

1. As soon as i remove `android:gravity="center"` hints shows but i need to show text from centre and show hints in edit text as well(Is it a bug in android sdk?).
2. i like to wrap text up-to a certain size if texts grows larger than textview bounds.Right now it goes beyond the view and doest not shows the entered digits after its ending but digits keeps on getting added in edit text.

Please if anyone have any idea how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Rishi are you got the solution of your first question? Please tell me I am stuck on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry Mansi i haven't got the answer to this question.

Comment: Ok.. Bad luck.. (: Anyway thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

To show all the text in the EditText just add:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

> As soon as i remove android:gravity="center" hints shows but i need to
>   show text from centre and show hints in edit text as well(Is it a bug
>   in android sdk?).

I don't understand what you mean at the fist point. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: First of all i need my edit text to be single line so i have set android:singleLine="true"

Comment: and gravity=center means i need to show my text starting from centre in edit text and if text field is empty the android:hint="This is my hint" will show. Just see the default android phone dialpad, when you enter number its shows the number typed from middle and shrinks in to a particular size.i need exactly same behavior,u can  assume i am implementing another dialpad of mine just like default android dialpad.

Answer (score 0):

1. (if i understand the question)android:gravity="center" allways refear to the "son" of the view. the "son" of  the EditText is the text. If you want to put the EditText in the center and the text in the center you should put other gravity=center in the tablerow.
2. You should change the size of the text programatically:

   if (myid.getText().toString().lengh()> XX )
                myid.setTextSize("xxdip")

   Or something like this